# Create path alias to a custom link

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a taxonomy term that has its own template, inside that template, there is custom links that just add a new argument to the URL
for example the current path is `/taxonomy/term/%`, one of the custom links will send the user to `/taxonomy/term/%/%`

with pathauto the url alias changes only when I visit `/taxonomy/term/%` (vocab_name/term_name), but it won't changed when I vist `/taxonomy/term/%/%`. I want it like that : vocab_name/term_name/%.

Is that possible ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to change the TAXONOMY TERM PATHS patern?

Comment: Of course I changed that, delete aliases and create again, only /taxonomy/term/% has been changed, when I visit /taxonomy/term/%/%my_arg the url still the same (/taxonomy/term/%/%my_arg)

Comment: what is your first argument %? how about the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Check [path_alias_xt](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt) and [subpathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto), I have used *subpathauto* to achieve this for nodes and *path_alias_xt* documentation says it does for taxonomy terms too.